# Selection Sort using Python

Tags: python, sorting, selection-sort

I *(A Python DS Beginner)* implemented this **SelectionSort() Algorithm** in **Python** by the way I was taught it in **Java.**

Is there any better way for sorting using *SelectionSort* using **Python**?.
Please help me out.

```
def selectionSort(arr,an):
    for lastUnsortedInteger in range(an-1,0,-1):
        ma = max(arr[0:lastUnsortedInteger+1])
        largest = arr.index(max(arr[0:lastUnsortedInteger+1]))
        swap(arr,largest,lastUnsortedInteger)
    return arr

def swap(arr,ai,aj):
    arr[ai],arr[aj] = arr[aj],arr[ai]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    an = int(input())
    arr = list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
    selectionSort(arr,an)
    print("Sorted using SelectionSort():\n")
    for ai in arr:
        print(arr)
```

Comment: Might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Just a few suggestions: You can swap in one line without tmp: `a, b = b, a`, and you could use the `min` or `max` builtin with an appropriate `key` function to select the index to swap.

Answer (score 0):

This is my implementation of selection sort, that seems to be the fastest, out of the other 2 implementations.

```
def SelectionSort_2(array): # Fastest implementation
    length = len(array)

    # Traverse through all array elements 
    for i in range(length): 

        # Find the minimum element in remaining unsorted array 
        min_idx = i 
        for j in range(i+1, length): 
            if array[min_idx] > array[j]: 
                min_idx = j 

        # Swap the found minimum element with the first element
        array[i], array[min_idx] = array[min_idx], array[i] 

    return array
```